# Using php to dynamically output an html table based on input from a form on the same page

Tags: php

I'm designing a web interface for my sql database. I ported this from an Access database that used separate forms for each of its queries. I could do that easily, but the forms are very similar and I can put them all into one just by using 3 html select boxes. I made the form, I have input for to/from date, one select to choose between totals of departments or employees, and one for selecting and individual department or employee. I would also like to do this without the use of JS if possible, I've only had to use JS as a print function so far.

First of all, I want the table to show on the same page as the form, but I don't care if I have to force it to refresh, for this I used `<form method="post action=""` and maybe `if(isset($_POST["Submit])){`. I have seen some controversy about the `action=""` but I thought it would work until I know what is appropriate to use in my case, which is why I'm pointing it out now.

Then I need to check the output of `$_POST`, this is something I don't know how to right a conditional for. So, for `$_POST["select-emp/dep"]` if the user selects department it would show one table, if the user selects employee it would be another. If the user leaves `$_POST["select-emp/dep"]` blank and chooses something from `$_POST["select-employee"]` or `$_POST["select-department"]` it will output another table. The conditions for those two should just be anything besides empty, they aren't handling any sql yet so that's fine I think. If more than one box is filled then I will have it display an error, same with if nothing is entered. I'm trying to think about it but is this just something as simple as `if($_POST["select-emp/dep"]("Department"))`?

Here is the code I have so far if I did not explain well enough:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Incidents Queries</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<div id="body">
<div id="nav">
        <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href='/incidents/index.php'>Index</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href='/incidents/employeestable.php'>Employees</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href='/incidents/departmentstable.php'>Departments</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href='/incidents/incidentstable.php'>Incidents</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href='/incidents/incidentsform.php'>Incidents Form</a></li></ul>
</div>

</div>

<div id="button">
<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
</div>

<div id="content">

<?php
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $db = "incidents";
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);
                if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
                }
        $sqlerror = $mysqli->errno . ' ' . $mysqli->error;
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<div class="row">
        <div id="col-25">
                <label for="date-from">Select a date range</label>
        </div>
                <div id="col-75">
                        <input type="date" id="date-from" name="date-from">
                        To
                        <input type="date" id="date-to" name="date-to">
                </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div id="col-25">
                <label for="select-emp/dep">Choose from one</label>
        </div>
                <div id="col-75">
                        <select id="select-emp/dep" name="select-emp/dep">
                                <option>Select one</option>
                                <option value="Department">Department</option>
                                <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
                        </select>
                        <select id="select-department" name="select-department">
                                <option>Select one</option>
                                <?php
                                        $dsql = "SELECT `Department` FROM departments";
                                        $dquery = mysqli_query($mysqli, $dsql);

                                        while ($dlist = mysqli_fetch_array($dquery)) {
                                                $d = $dlist['Department'];
                                                echo '<option value="'. $d .'">' . $d . '</option>';
                                        }
                                ?>
                        </select>
                        <select id="select-employee" name="select-employee">
                                <option>Select one</option>
                                <?php
                                        $esql = "SELECT `Employee` FROM employees";
                                        $equery = mysqli_query($mysqli, $esql);

                                        while ($elist = mysqli_fetch_array($equery)) {
                                                $e = $elist['Employee'];
                                                echo '<option value="'. $e .'">' . $e . '</option>';
                                        }
                                ?>
</select>
                </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div id="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
        </div>
</div>

</form>
<br>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
        if($_POST["select-emp/dep"] *This needs to be conditional* ?>
         *table code goes here*

<?php endif
        if($_POST["select-emloyee"]               ?>
              <table>

<?php endif
        if($_POST["select-department"]            ?>
              <table>

<php endif
} ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["select-emp/dep"]))` should be the if condition...you've already got the right syntax when testing the "submit" field on the line just above!

Comment: But...this won't really work, because your select will never be blank - always one option will be selected, even if it's just the default. It would be better to check the actual value, rather than whether it is set. Give your default option a value e.g. `<option value="-">Select one</option` and then you can test for it e.g. `if($_POST["select-emp/dep"] == "-")` or `if($_POST["select-emp/dep"] != "-")` (depending on the outcome you want)

Comment: ok so should `isset` be used for each one? From what I understand that would work for `$_POST["select-employee"]` or department, but `$_POST["select-emp/dep"] has a different table for each of its results, so I still need a condition for that

Comment: Read my second comment again :-)

Comment: @ADyson Shouldn't the default value for the select boxes just come back as empty? I don't know if `isset` would be sensitive to the empty value though.

Comment: In a HTML form if you don't specify a value for an option then (if that option is selected) usually it just sends the text of the option as the value instead. And in most browsers, if the user doesn't explicitly set an option then the default value is treated as being the value of the first option in the list. They're never considered to be empty. try it and see.

Comment: I tested that with one of my other forms and it just leaves the fields blank